# why powershell terminal in vscode show path

Tags: powershell, terminal, visual-studio-code

I have an issue in using terminal in vscode . actually I am using terminal for 1 year and today when I want to use terminal,it showes these:

PowerShell 7.1.3Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.
https://aka.ms/powershell
Type 'help' to get help.
PS C:\Programming\python\IT_python\python_senior_review_1>PS C:\Programming\python\IT_python\python_senior_review_1> cd c:/Programming/python/IT_python/python_senior_reviewPS C:\Programming\python\IT_python\python_senior_review_1> cd c:/Programming/python/IT_python/python_senior_review_1/listsPS C:\Programming\python\IT_python\python_senior_review_1\lists>

and I have to resize the terminal window for show my code everytime.
anybody knowes how to remove these?
(I imported terminal images too.)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2uTot.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WjXzt.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you haven't tried updating VSCode and Powershell, that would be a good place to start.

You can also try setting your VSCode Powershell profile, that might force it to fix that line width issue: https://superuser.com/questions/446827/configure-windows-powershell-to-display-only-the-current-folder-name-in-the-shel

You could also try changing your screen resolution settings to see if that affects it.

Hope at least one of these helps. I couldn't find much from Googling either.

Edit: apparently this is an issue with the current version of VSCode (https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/128342)

Comment: thank you.I deleted my vscode new version and install version 1.56.

Answer (score 0):

actually this problem is for new version of vscode(1.58).I unistalled 1.58 and then install version 1.57 and this issue solved.